# How to use IOS default calendar from my app and get back to my app again

Tags: ios, ios-urlsheme

I am developing an App and i need to get  access of the IOS Default calendar and come back to my application. I am using `URL` Scheme of calshow:// to go to the app and it is successfully working but how to come back to my application again please suggest me.

And i know that while creating an event if we enter any application `Urlscheme`in the url text field provided by the calendar and create the event then if we click that url will take to that app from the calendar app. But it may confuse the user and it is not a good one to do. Tell me any other simple way that i can switch between my app to Calendar and vice versa with out having any headache for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openurl:[NSUrl UrlWithString:@"calshow://"] 
to navigate to calendar app